# unscrambling cloudflare protected email using R instead of Python?

Tags: r, web-scraping, cloudflare

I have a pretty simple script in R that pulls meta information from journals. The current issue is that the journals that I had scraped before (e.g. Sage Journals) are now using cloudflare to block scrapers.

Is there a package in R to unscramble the cloudflare email blockers?  Or should I just use python?